# How to write a function to filter event on Spring Application Event

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Assume that I have a publisher

```
@Data
public class FooEvent {
  String name;
}

@Component
public class FooPublisher {
  @Autowired
  ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

  public void myBusinessFunction() {
    ...doSomething...
    publisher.publishEvent(new FooEvent("fooName");
  }
}
```

Now I want to create an EventListener for this event

```
@Component
public class MyEventListener {
  @EventListener(condition = "filter(event.name)")
  public void handleFoo(FooEvent event) {
    sout(event);
  }

  public boolean filter(String name) {
    return name.equals("test");
  }
}
```

My EventListener wants to have a custom filter with a function inside my MyEventListener.

Of course, this function is not working because of `condition = "filter(event.name)"`

How can I write a custom filter in the condition of @EventListener?

Comment: Use SpEL. Something like `event.name == 'test'` in your case.

Comment: I read some document about SpEL, but the bad news for me is it could not call internal function of the current object
Because of the inside `filter` function, I want to do many jobs rather than only compare string

Comment: What do you mean by internal function of current object? Currenlty you are already calling a function? If things are more complex then a simle expression write a java method and call it. Don't program in a SpEL expression.

Comment: I mean I wrote a java function name `filter` to handle a complex logic. Can I use it in SpEL?

Comment: Something like `#this.filter(event.name)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I found how to handle this, EventListener SpEl support bean resolver so that we can use all bean in ApplicationContext

```
@Component("beanName")
public class MyEventListener {
  @EventListener(condition = "@beanName.filter(event.name)")
  public void handleFoo(FooEvent event) {
    sout(event);
  }

  public boolean filter(String name) {
    return name.equals("test");
  }
}
```